# Adding iterator to a pointer

Tags: c++

```
struct Region
{
    Name name_;
    std::vector<RegionID*> lower_regions_;
    RegionID *upper_region_;
    std::vector<StopID*> stop_id_;
};

struct Stop
{
    Name name_;
    Coord coord_;
    RegionID *region_id_;
};



std::unordered_map<StopID, Stop> stops_;
std::unordered_map<RegionID, Region> regions_;
```

Here are my map and struct which contain information about bus stops and different regions they are located.

```
bool Datastructures::add_stop_to_region(StopID id, RegionID parentid) {
    std::unordered_map<StopID, Stop>::iterator stop = stops_.find(id);
    if (stop == stops_.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    std::unordered_map<RegionID, Region>::iterator region = regions_.find(parentid);
    if (region == regions_.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (stop->second.region_id_ != NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    //error: nvalid conversion from ?const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>* to RegionID* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*?} [-fpermissive]
    stop->second.region_id_ = &region->first;

    //error: no matching function for call to push_back(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)
    region->second.stop_id_.push_back(&stop->first);
    return true;

}
```

I don't understand why i cant add the key from map to the pointer(The last 3 code lines). And i don't want to store the RegionID or StopID as a value to the struct because else i would need to search the key from map every time i need the value from the RegionID or StopID.

Comment: Storing pointers you acquire with `&` for later is not a good idea unless you're very careful, since the objects they point to will often be destroyed by the time you want to use them. This is the case here.

Comment: Seconding @molbdnilo - given the usual semantics of something named "ID" it is highly unlikely you ever want to store a pointer to one, and especially not have a container of pointers-to-IDs.  I believe you're somewhat confused between IDs and pointers and also what it means to have a pointer to an ID (or a pointer to a pointer) - especially a changable one.  That design is probably what you should consider - i.e., study what it means - in order to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `unordered_map`, the key is `const`.  You can't change it.  An iterator for an unordered map gives access to a particular (key, value) pair stored in the map.  As such, the `first` value of the iterator is a const value.  In both of your errors, you are attempting to store a pointer to this const value into a structure that holds non-const (modifiable) values.

You can fix the error by changing `region_id_` to be a `const RegionID *` and `stop_id_` to be a `std::vector<const StopID*>`, so that both are constant pointers, but this may cause problems later if you try to write thru these pointers.